# R Markdown "function %>% not found"

Tags: r-markdown

I have a problem with R Markdown. In the Markdown file, I start by loading the necessary packages (including tidyverse) in a code chunk. But in the last code chunk, an error pops up which says

> "could not find function %>% Calls:  ...withVisible ->
> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval Execution halted"

Can you please explain why this occurs and how I can fix it?
Thanks!

As requested:
This is the first code chunk where I load the packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(psych)
options(scipen = 999)
```

And, this is the code chunk where the error occurs:

```
DE_GDP_1965_2020 <- DE_GDP_1965_1969 %>%
  full_join(DE_GDP_1970_2020)
model <- lm(GDP ~ Period, data = DE_GDP_1965_2020)
summary(model)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: Without seeing what you did, we probably can't help.  Don't show us your whole file, just keep the first and last code chunks (or parts of them if they are long), and edit the minimal example into your question. If you are executing `library(tidyverse)` then you shouldn't get the error you describe.

Comment: I added the code chunks